# Validating a subset of List items using Java Hibernate, aquiring the full property path

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am creating my first spring boot web application using javax and hibernate to validate data input from a JSP form. I have a Booking model that includes a List of Journeys models:

```
@ValidBooking(groups = {BookingI.class})
public class Booking {

  @Min(value = 1, groups = {BookingI.class, Default.class})
  private int totalJourneys;
  @Valid
  private List<Journey> journeys;
  // relevant getters and setters
```

I need to know how to validate only a selection of the Journey items on form submission, now the complication comes where the Journey model contains a List of Locations:

```
@ValidJourney
public class Journey {

  @Valid
  private List<Location> locations;
  private List<String> dates;
  private List<String> times;

  // relevant getters and setters
```

I can successfully validate all Booking Journeys using the `@Valid` annotation, however on form submission I am only interested in the success of certain Journeys, so would like to ignore certain Journey item constraint violations.

My attempt so far has been to use a custom class validator to iterate over and validate only the required journeys, then use a buildConstraint ViolationWithTemplate as follows:

```
public class ValidBookingValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidBooking, Booking> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Booking booking, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    int totalJourneys = booking.getTotalJourneys();
    int validJourneys = 0;
    for (int journeyIdx = 0; journeyIdx < totalJourneys; journeyIdx++) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Journey>> journeyConstraintViolations = validator.validate(booking.getJourneys().get(journeyIdx));

        if (journeyConstraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
            validJourneys++;
        } else {
            for (ConstraintViolation<Journey> violation : journeyConstraintViolations) {
                constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
                .addPropertyNode(violation.getPropertyPath().toString())
                .addConstraintViolation();
            }
        }
    }
    return totalJourneys == validJourneys;
  }

}
```

The above code works for my tests, however when rendering using jsp forms the spring data binding fails as the property path of the offending violation constraint returns as 'locations[0]' instead of the expected 'booking.journeys[0].locations[0]'.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to return the full property path, or provide a better solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

`Java 8, javax validation api 2.0.1, hibernate-validator 6.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of comments first:

- it's not a good idea to build a `ValidatorFactory` in a validator. It's a very heavy object and it will require building the metadata of your `Journey` bean every time you validate it and it's going to be slow.
- to build your constraint, you need to build the exact path i.e. use `inContainer()`, `atIndex()`... you can't simply pass the `toString()` to a property.

For sure you can fix the latter but the former is definitely a no-no.

There's something you can try:

- create a `JourneyDefaultGroupSequenceProvider` that implements `DefaultGroupSequenceProvider` and return the valid group(s) when it's an object you want to validate and some random group not used in any constraint when you don't want to validate the journey. `List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(T object)` has an instance of your object so you can do that here.
- declare it with

  ```
  @GroupSequenceProvider(JourneyDefaultGroupSequenceProvider.class)
  public class Journey {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- remove all the quirks you added and validate your `Booking` bean normally.

Update: I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1613 to see if we can provide a more natural way to do it in HV.

Comment: Thanks for the response and advice @GuillaumeSmet, I am in the process of implementing the GroupSequenceProvider. 
My only question is can I access the Parent Object information (in this case Booking) within the Journey GroupSequenceProvider, so I can identify if the index position of the Journey object is less than the Booking.totalJourneys value?

Comment: You have only the very instance where you have the `@GroupSequenceProvider`. So you need a link to the parent in your object unfortunately. FYI I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1613 to consider adding something more obvious. Will add your case about the index in it but I'm not sure it would be easy to find a solution to that.